# Converting rows into columns in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have table `subs_details` sample data and columns like:

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4579 |
| 2 | 5678 |
| 3 | 6678 |
| 2 | 7803 |
| 1 | 5479 |
| 3 | 5779 |

I want to convert it into below output:

| ID1 | id1_number | id2 | id2_number | id3 | id3_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4579 | 2 | 5678 | 3 | 6678 |
| 1 | 5479 | 2 | 7803 | 3 | 5779 |

Please help in this

Comment: I've edited your question to provide better formatting. Please, be familiar how to do this (press `Edit` to look at the actual message) in future on your own. But I'm not sure if you really want to get the result in the form above. Please, edit your question if it's not what you want or confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

You may run it as is.

```
WITH 
  MYTAB (ID, Number) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 4579)
, (2, 5678)
, (3, 6678)
, (2, 7803)
, (1, 5479)
, (3, 5779)
)
, MYTAB_NUMBERED AS
(
SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS RN_
FROM MYTAB T
)
SELECT 
  1 AS ID1, T1.NUMBER AS ID1_NUMBER
, 2 AS ID2, T2.NUMBER AS ID2_NUMBER  
, 3 AS ID3, T3.NUMBER AS ID3_NUMBER
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RN_ FROM MYTAB_NUMBERED) N
LEFT JOIN MYTAB_NUMBERED T1 ON T1.RN_ = N.RN_ AND T1.ID = 1
LEFT JOIN MYTAB_NUMBERED T2 ON T2.RN_ = N.RN_ AND T2.ID = 2
LEFT JOIN MYTAB_NUMBERED T3 ON T3.RN_ = N.RN_ AND T3.ID = 3
```

| ID1 | ID1_NUMBER | ID2 | ID2_NUMBER | ID3 | ID3_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4,579 | 2 | 5,678 | 3 | 6,678 |
| 1 | 5,479 | 2 | 7,803 | 3 | 5,779 |